# Pass dictionary of numpy arrays to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this:

I'm using a straightforward selection sort function like so:

```
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint

# We start with a function that finds the smallest 
#value in our array

def findSmallest(arr):
    smallest = arr[0] # stores the smallest value
    smallestIndex = 0 # stores the index of the 
                      # smallest value
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < smallest:
            smallest = arr[i]
            smallestIndex = i
    return smallestIndex

# Our findSmallest function can be used in the 
  #selection sort algorithm

def selectionSort(arr):
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        smallest = findSmallest(arr) 
        newArr.append(arr.pop(smallest)) 
    return smallestIndex
```

Then, instead of making each array I need one at a time, I run a loop to return a dictionary containing all arrays:

```
arraySizes = (5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000)

myArray = dict()

for size in arraySizes:
    myArray[size] = randint(99999, size = size)
```

This works:

```
print(myArray[10000])
```

***Based on conversation in the comments, I'm amending my question, but will leave the original question below the dashed line down a bit farther***

Ok. So I was way off base in how I thought the ** worked when passing an array to a function.

What I still can't figure out, is how to run a loop that passes the values from each key to a function and returns objects that work with the selectionSort function above.

So, I want to pass 
       {5000:10,2,...n, 10000:10000,200...n,etc}

to selectionSort and end up with something along the lines of objects that are 
       sort5000 = [2,10,...n]
       sort10000 = [200,...n,10000]

That's not quite right, but hopefully gets across my goal. If not, please let me know.

---

But, when I try to pass it to the above selectionSort:

```
selectionSort(**myArray[5000])
```

I get the error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                  Traceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-21-bc709916eed6> in <module>()
----> 1 selectionSort(**myArray[5000])

TypeError: selectionSort() argument after ** must be a mapping, not 
numpy.ndarray
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. Should I rewrite the selectionSort so that it returns a dict of arrays? Is there a way to pass the values from the dict one at a time? Am I just going about this all wrong and should just build several arrays and pass them one at a time?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why the `**`? What was your intent there?

Comment: Also NumPy arrays are not Python lists, and you cannot treat them the same. An array has no `pop`.

Comment: The intent was to be able to create a ton of arrays without creating an object for each one, then pass them all to a function without having to pass each one

Comment: So, should I just suck it up and make them all individually?

Comment: That is not what `**` does, and also you've picked out an individual array anyway with the `[5000]` in `myArray[5000]`.

Comment: So, when I initially used just the **myArray, I got an TypeError: selectionSort() keywords must be strings error

Comment: I thought the ** had the function pass the values and * did the keys.

I'm clearly learning here, so I'm sure all of this is way off base

Comment: Yup, that's way off base. `**` is keyword argument unpacking. It takes a mapping and passes the entries to a function as keyword arguments, which makes no sense for `selectionSort(**myArray[5000])` because `myArray[5000]` isn't a mapping, and also makes no sense for `selectionSort(**myArray)` because the keys are ints, not strings representing keywords. Also, `selectionSort` only takes a single array anyway.

Comment: Normally a `foo(**adict)` is used with a `def foo(**kwargs)` definition.  In other words, the function is designed to accept a keywords argument.  Within `foo`, `kwargs` is a dictionary.

Comment: Ok, (and sorry about the extended comments), does that mean I should be wrapping the selectionSort into something that can pass each array to it individually, or that this is just a real dumb way to do this in the first place? (Talking about up to the creation of the array dict, not the (**myArray part-- that's clearly not right...and thanks for the explainer)

Comment: Why not just call `selectionSort` in a loop?

Comment: I tried, but couldn't figure out how to isolate the values...I get a TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() when I run "for arr in myArray:
    selectionSort(arr)"